# How to add working dropify inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropify

I have form which gets clone when user click on add more button .

This is how my html looks:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content">
    <div class="item-block">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-float btn-remove">
            <i class="ti-close"></i>
        </button>
        <input type="file" id="drop" class="dropify" data-default-file="https://cdn.example.com/front2/assets/img/logo-default.png" name="sch_logo">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-duplicator">Add experience</button>
    ...
</div>
```

This my jquery part :

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".btn-duplicator").on("click", function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();          
        var b = $(this).parent().siblings(".duplicateable-content"),
        c = $("<div>").append(b.clone(true, true)).html();          
        $(c).insertBefore(b);
        var d = b.prev(".duplicateable-content");
        d.fadeIn(600).removeClass("duplicateable-content")
    })
});
```

Now I want every time user clicks on add more button the id and class of the input type file should be changed into an unique, some may be thinking why I'm doing this, it I because dropify plugin doesn't work after being cloned, but when I gave it unique id and class it started working, here is what I've tried :

```
function randomString(len, an){
    an = an&&an.toLowerCase();
    var str="", i=0, min=an=="a"?10:0, max=an=="n"?10:62;
    for(;i++<len;){
      var r = Math.random()*(max-min)+min <<0;
      str += String.fromCharCode(r+=r>9?r<36?55:61:48);
    }
    return str;
} var ptr = randomString(10, "a");
var className = $('#drop').attr('class');
var cd =    $("#drop").removeClass(className).addClass(ptr);
```

Now after this here is how I initiate the plugin `$('.' + ptr).dropify()`.

But because id is still same I'm not able to produce clone more than one.

How can I change the id and class everytime user click on it? is there a better way?

Comment: to set a attribute value in JQuery you could use the setter method for attr() e.g. `$('#drop').attr('class','YOURCLASSNAME');` or `$('#drop').attr('id','YOURIDNAME');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/21375/)**.

> **Problem :**
> You're cloning a div that contain already initialized dropify input and that what create the conflict when you're trying to clone it and reinitilize it after clone for the second time.
>
> **Solution:** Create a model div for the dropify div you want to clone without adding `dropify` class to prevent `$('.dropify').dropify()` from initialize the input then add class `dropify` during the clone.

**Model div code :**

```
<div class='hidden'>
    <div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content model">
        <div class="item-block">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-float btn-remove">
                X
            </button>
            <input type="file" data-default-file="http://www.misterbilingue.com/assets/uploads/fileserver/Company%20Register/game_logo_default_fix.png" name="sch_logo">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-duplicator">Add experience</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS code :**

```
$('.dropify').dropify();

$("body").on("click",".btn-duplicator", clone_model);
$("body").on("click",".btn-remove", remove);

//Functions
function clone_model() {
  var b = $(this).parent(".duplicateable-content"),
      c = $(".model").clone(true, true);

  c.removeClass('model');
  c.find('input').addClass('dropify');

  $(b).before(c);
  $('.dropify').dropify();
}

function remove() {
  $(this).closest('.duplicateable-content').remove();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: as i said I'm cloning the form, after cloning the dropify looks perfect but it doesn't function. for e.g if i click on file doesn't show

Comment: are you calling `$('.dropify').dropify();` after the clone ? because the plugin should be initialized after adding new elements.

Comment: after i clone the form dropify is totally duplicated but it doesn't function, then i called $('.dropify').dropify(); but then there was to x button 2 browse button & dropify became a mess

Comment: @AniketSingh check the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/21370/

Comment: Thanks your code is working perfectly fine but there is one more prob c.find('input').addClass('dropify'); is changing all input text into dropify. i only want to select input file

Comment: You're welcome, `c.find('input[name="sch_logo"]').addClass('dropify');` should do the work, check my update ...

Comment: One more  Zakaria Acharki when i click on add button it clones one form but when i click it again it clones two form, do you know why?

Comment: Still same, if i click again and again on the first add more button you will find the problem

Comment: Sorry check now its ok .. ;)

Comment: Don't need to be sorry sir, thanks for helping, Now add more button is not working

Comment: :( works for me if i click 10 times 10 div will be cloned .. in the fiddle

Comment: This one works for me https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/21375/ .. click on any "Add experience" and count the clicks then count the number of cloned divs.

Comment: Why have you added 2 duplicateable-content div?

Comment: The first is a model div and its hidden will be cloned every time you click, the second is a default one non removable and from it you could begin clones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-duplicator", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    var b = $(this).parent(".duplicateable-content"),
      c = b.clone(true, true);
    c.find(".dropify").removeClass('dropify').addClass('cropify')
      .attr('id', b.find('[type="file"]')[0].id + $(".btn-duplicator").index(this)) //<here
    $(c).insertBefore(b);
    var d = b.prev(".duplicateable-content");
    d.fadeIn(600).removeClass("duplicateable-content")
  })
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cna0y0su/)

Answer (score 0):

This does  what you specified with an example different from yours:

```
<div id="template"><span>...</span></div>
<script>
function appendrow () {
html = $('#template').html();
var $last = $('.copy').last();
var lastId;
if($last.length > 0) {
    lastId = parseInt($('.copy').last().prop('id').substr(3));
} else {
    lastId = -1;
}
$copy = $(html);
$copy.prop('id', 'row' + (lastId + 1));
$copy.addClass('copy');
if(lastId < 0)
    $copy.insertAfter('#template');
else
    $copy.insertAfter("#row" + lastId);
}

appendrow();
appendrow();
appendrow();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one class to all dropify inputs (e.g. 'dropify'). Then you can set each elements ID to a genereted value using this:

```
inputToAdd.attr('id', 'dropify-input-' + $('.dropify').length );
```

Each time you add another button, $('.dropify').length will increase by 1 so you and up having a unique ID for every button.